# Why can I omit the parameter name to a function?

Tags: go

I accidentally wrote something like this code (simplified to a minimal example):

```
func f(...interface{}) int {
    return 4
}
```

I think it should be:

```
func f(args ...interface{}) int {
    return 4
}
```

Why does the go compiler allow the version without a parameter name, and what does it mean?

Comment: The language spec allows this.

Comment: but why, what does it mean

Comment: It means you're ignoring that input variable. Which you are.

Comment: Hi Alex, I heavily edited your question. It's clearer for readers on the site to see a minimal example that demonstrates the question without extraneous stuff. I think (hope) I preserved the spirit of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use anonymous function parameters in case you want to satisfy an interface, for example, but do not access the parameter in question.

Given

```
package main

import "fmt"


type Greeter interface {
    // Note that the Greet function requires a parameter
    Greet(string) string
}

// GenericGreeter is the most basic Greeter.
type WorldGreeter struct {
}

// Greet satisfies the Greeter interface, which requires a string parameter for
// the Greet function.
func (g GenericGreeter) Greet(string) string {
    // Now, here is the thing: We do not access
    // the parameter, hence it can be anonymous.
    return "Hello, World!"
}

func PrintGreeting(g Greeter) {
    fmt.Println(g.Greet(""))
}

func main() {
    PrintGreeting(&GenericGreeter{})
}
```

That was pretty much the same with your code: you declared a function parameter, but did not use it.

Comment: For completeness: you can omit the receiver name too. `func (GenericGreeter) Greet(string) string {`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Volker this is allowed by the language spec and I understand your confusion what it is used for.

When you don't name the parameters you cannot access their values. But in rare cases you actually don't need to. When you have an interface you want to implement that declares parameters, but they are not needed for your implementation, then there is no need to name them, for example when you are writing mocks:

```golang
type Foo interface {
    Bar(string)
}

type MockFoo struct {}

func (MockFoo) Bar(string) {
    // Do nothing
}
```